# DELETE and CREATE instead of UPDATE with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For Some Reason.

I want to DELETE and CREATE instead of UPDATE for Nested Form.

**normal update is work**

```
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @post.update!(update_params)
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    puts "ERROR"
  end
```

**I want to change to like (not work)**

```
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @post.attributes = update_params

      @post.post_categories.each do |pc|
        if pc.changed?
          pc.mark_for_destruction
        end
      end
      @post.save!
      @post.attributes = update_params
      @post.save!
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    puts "ERROR"
  end
```

### Source Code

**This is normal update version all code**.
https://github.com/shingo-nakanishi/workout_rails/tree/v5.0

**Post**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_categories, inverse_of: :post
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_categories,
                                allow_destroy: true,
                                reject_if: :is_reject

  private

  def is_reject(attributes)
    is_exist = attributes[:id].present?
    is_empty = attributes[:post_category_id].blank?
    attributes.merge!(_destroy: 1) if is_exist and is_empty
    !is_exist and is_empty
  end
end
```

**PostCategory**

```
class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :post_categories
  belongs_to :post_category_master
end
```

**PostCategoryMaster**

```
class PostCategoryMaster < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**PostsController**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.post_categories.build
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(create_params)
    @post.save!
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    puts "ERROR"
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    unless @post.post_categories.present?
      @post.post_categories.build
    end
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @post.attributes = update_params

      @post.post_categories.each do |pc|
        if pc.changed?
          pc.mark_for_destruction
        end
      end
      @post.save!
      @post.attributes = update_params
      @post.save!
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    puts "ERROR"
  end

  private
  def create_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:description, post_categories_attributes: [:post_category_id])
  end

  def update_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:description, post_categories_attributes: [:id, :post_category_id])
  end
end
```

**view/posts/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :description %><%= f.text_field :description %><br/>
    <%= f.fields_for :post_categories do |b| %>
        <%= b.label :post_category_id %>
        <%= b.collection_select :post_category_id,
                                PostCategoryMaster.all,
                                :id,
                                :name,
                                multiple: true,
                                include_blank: 'none',
                                prompt: 'please select' %>
    <% end -%>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

### I tried

Please see above **PostsController#update**.
Use **mark_for_destruction**, then assign same update_params.

Get Error

> Couldn't find PostCategory with ID=31 for Post with ID=36

How to DELETE and CREATE instead of UPDATE for Nested Form.

Answer (score 0):

### Nested attributes create nested records in the same request.

I think you are basically confused about how nested attributes are supposed to work.

Nested attributes allow you to create :post_categories when you:

```
POST "/posts"
```

And update both the post and the categories with:

```
UPDATE "/posts/:id"
```

That means that adding/removing `PostCategories` on an existing `Post` will always use `update` (PUT/PATCH).

But when you use `collection_select` it does not use nested attributes at all. Instead it creates an array of ids that are passed to the models `*_ids=` setter. When you set `post.post_category_ids= [1]` on your model it removes / adds associations.

Note that it's `post_category_ids` in plural. However your form is incorrect as it should not be inside the `f.fields_for :post_categories` block.

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :description %><%= f.text_field :description %><br/>
    <%= b.label :post_category_ids %>
    <%= b.collection_select :post_category_ids,
                            PostCategoryMaster.all,
                            :id,
                            :name,
                            multiple: true,
                            include_blank: 'none',
                            prompt: 'please select' 
    %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
private
  def create_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:description, post_category_ids: [])
  end

  def update_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:description, post_category_ids: [])
  end
```

Creating form elements that use nested attributes to add / delete is quite a bit more complicated.

### POST / DELETE for nested records.

If you wanted to use the POST / DELETE verbs to act on the associated categories you would have to create additional routes and a controller.

Note that accepts_nested_attributes is pointless in this case as its not even going to be used.

```
resources :posts do
  resources :categories
end
```

Then you would use

```
POST "/posts/:post_id/categories" # to create a post.
DELETE "/posts/:post_id/categories/:id" # to destroy a post.
```

And you would have to create a form for each category (or use button_for).

```
<%= @categories.each do |c| %>
  <%= button_to "Delete", post_categories_path(post_id: c.post, id: c), method: :delete, confirm: "Are you sure?" %>
<% end %>
```